# Integrals using FTC 1 and 2

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Please excuse the format!

The question asks to calculate:

$$\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow 0}{\frac{1}{h} \int\limits_{3}^{3+h}{e^{t^2} dt}}$$

I know to calculate the integral first. So by FTC, we know how to calculate the integral from a (constant) to x. I'm just thrown off by the 3 and 3+h.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:
$\lim \limits_{h \to 0} \dfrac{ \int_3^{3+h} e^{t^2} \; dt}{h}$ is an indeterminant form $\frac{0}{0}$ . . .

Comment: L'Hospital! Thank you!
I got 6e^3
I hope that's correct!

Comment: @StephanieHernandez alternatively, one can note that the expression is the limit of a difference quotient, i.e. a derivative.

Comment: using the mean value theorem?

Answer (score 0):

You can also observe that $$e^{9}h\leq\int_{3}^{3+h}e^{t^{2}}dt\leq he^{\left(3+h\right)^{2}}
 $$ so $$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\int_{3}^{3+h}e^{t^{2}}dt}{h}=\color{red}{e^{9}}$$ by squeeze theorem.

Comment: Oh I see, you multiplied by h and applied the squeeze theorem. Did you differentiate the ends?

Comment: @StephanieHernandez No, I used $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx\leq(b-a)\max f(x)$, and similarly for the minimum. Then you have only to calculate the limits and conclude using the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $$\frac{1}{h} \int_{3}^{3+h}{e^{t^2} dt}=\frac{ \int_{3}^{3+h}{e^{t^2} dt}}{h}$$ which is $\frac 0 0$. SO apply L'Hospital rule and consider $$\frac{\frac d {dh} \int_{3}^{3+h}{e^{t^2} dt}}{\frac {dh} {dh}}={\frac d {dh} \int_{3}^{3+h}{e^{t^2} dt}}$$ Now, use the fundamental theorem of calculus which, for the most general case, write $${\frac d {dh} \int_{a(h)}^{b(h)}{f(t)\, dt}}=f(b(h))\, b'(h)-f(a(h))\, a'(h)$$ In your case $$b(h)=3+h\implies b'(h)=1$$  $$a(h)=3\implies a'(h)=0$$ All of this makes $${\frac d {dh} \int_{3}^{3+h}{e^{t^2} dt}}=e^{(3+h)^2}\to e^9$$